# How can I deactivate the login password on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian

I would to know how I can deactivate the login password on my Raspberry Pi? I need to login automatically after entering the following command on terminal:

```
ssh pi@<IP_address>
```

i.e., it should not ask for password to login.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is **NOT** recommended to disable the SSH password if your device is going to publicly available - for example connected to the internet with SSH port forwarder.

To disable SSH login authentication you need to edit some files:

1. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

   - Edit that file
2. `PasswordAuthentication yes` - `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes` - `UsePAM yes`

   - find those lines and make sure they are `no` and have no `#` in front.

Restart SSHD or the Pi

If you get a message

> Permission denied (publickey)

then set these in sshd_config to `no`,

```
RSAAuthentication yes

PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Restart SSHD or the Pi

**TIPS**

In sshd_config you can add. So it will only ask root for password,

```
Match User !root
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

And then you add a new user with limited permissions.Always log in as that user and when you need to do something as root you can just use `sudo "command"` - enter the root password and it will do it and come back to your low privilege user.

- To elevate into a root console from low privilege just type `sudo` enter your password. Once you are done type `exit` and you will drop back to the low privilege user.
- Did I already say that removing root user password and ssh key login is a very bad idea on a device that will be publicly available. Never do this on a public device!
- [Here is a guide how to setup up private/public keys](http://www.debuntu.org/ssh-key-based-authentication)

Comment: Also the SSH keys is a popular way to avoid entering passwords and is much better than just removing / avoiding / bypassing your passwords. But I answered your specific question- I hope these other suggestions/answers will help you too. Thanks and Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I changed PasswordAuthentication yes in file sshd_config to PasswordAuthentication no. But when I restarted the pi and entered the following command ssh pi@(IP Address),it shows Permission denied (publickey). I tried to add new user then it shows error connection (ssh pi@IP address) refused. I would like to know ,Why?

Comment: Well it looks like the SSH keys kick after you disable the password. It is a redundant security feature of what gfelisberto is talking about... I added how to remove that- But again its not a good idea- but that is what your question is about and maybe others will need to the same for internal testing.

Comment: Ok,I agree with you. Its not a good idea.However I would like to do this for a testing purpose

Comment: Isn't it really sufficient to just use `PasswordAuthentication no` to disable password login? Is it really required to set also `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` and `UsePAM no` ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki Honestly, yes, I can't see why the other settings are needed since it becomes impossible to log in with a password simply by changing `PasswordAuthentication` to `no`. If there is a reason, though, it'd be good is someone could update the answer to explain.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of not using passwords what you need is SSH keys: [SSH with authentication key instead of password](https://web.archive.org/web/20121031213812/http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/530).

After configuring key authentication you can then remove the password from the local (client) key and `ssh pi@rasp` will just work. But only from a machine that has the key.

Comment: Exactly the correct instructions for this case.

Comment: Hi,I tried to solve the problem following the link you had shown, but how I can copy the key from my desktop to pi using ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub ?

Comment: @sumith Use your password once to transfer the file or transfer the key using a USB key.