# Putty SSH, can't log into Raspberry

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-zero, putty

Heyo, I use my raspberry pi zero as an rgb strip controller behind my desk, I have a simple http/php server running on it so I can change the color from my web browser, it is powered by a phone charger and also connected directly to my pc via the second usb port, and that's how it gets it's internet. Thing is, every morning I have to go into putty, log in with the default pi/raspberry username and password and type in sudo pigpiod so I can start controlling the strip online... This takes about a minute and I thought I'd just shorten it 2x by removing the login bs, tried finding any results on how and didn't have great luck, but I did find this post: [How can I deactivate the login password on my Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/how-can-i-deactivate-the-login-password-on-my-raspberry-pi/3439) .
I followed it's instructions and made sure to set those settings to no, restarted my pi and putty. And now when I try to log in putty still asks for a username, and if I type anything in at all it brings me this message: "disconnected: no supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)" and I can't get into my pi through putty... the equipment I used to set it up (keyboard/mouse/usb hub/ 5 adapters for all the connections) is who knows where in the attic so I'll just leave it be and live without rgb if there is no simple solution within putty >_>

Comment: Try writing in paragraphs

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution to start automatically pigpio :

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joan2937/pigpio/master/util/pigpiod.service
sudo cp pigpiod.service /etc/systemd/system
sudo systemctl enable pigpiod.service
sudo systemctl start pigpiod.service
```

So when you start your raspberry pi, pigpiod start automatically and so you don't have to connect to your raspberry pi with putty.

Hope this will help you :).

Comment: Isn't the service already installed on Raspbian and just needs enabling? Option Remote GPIO in `raspi-config`

Comment: Here is the link where I found that solution : https://github.com/guymcswain/pigpio-client/wiki/Install-and-configure-pigpiod